# New commit won't `git pull` but `git reset` works

Tags: git, gitlab

I don't know how this happened but a change was pushed to Gitlab, the new commit is at the top of the commit history in Gitlab, but if you `git pull` you don't get it. Even a fresh `git clone` gives you the second most recent commit. Running `git log -1` doesn't show the new commit. The only thing I've found that works is to copy the SHA from Gitlab and `git reset` to that SHA.

What is up with this ghost commit that's visible in Gitlab but unreachable from the CLI unless you know its secret SHA?

Comment: `git pull` is pulling from **that** branch? Cause it might be looking at another branch as the upstream of the branch you are pulling from.

Comment: Or rather. ".... you are pulling into."

Comment: Probably the wrong branch, as eftshift0 suggested. Or there is some ambiguity going on (e.g. a tag name that's the same as branch). What does `git branch -r --contains <SHA>` give you? Does it mention the branch?

Also is this about gitlab.com or a self-hosted Gitlab instance? If it's self-hosted maybe somebody messed with the file permissions on the server's repository folder or changed which systems users are used for ssh and there is an issue with reading the updated branch head when accessing the repository via ssh (for pull).